# How to output the lowest and highest values from a data file using dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++, ifstream, bubble-sort, dynamic-arrays

I'm having trouble outputting the lowest and highest values of the integers contained in a txt file.

My directions are to set up a dynamic array to hold the exact number of values in the array and read the values from the file into the array.

After the values are in the array, sort them using a bubble sort. And then to output the lowest and highest values in the array.

===========================================================

I'm not allowed to use vectors unfortunately. :(

---

Here's the code I've written thank you for any help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int[], int);
void printArray(int[], int);

int main()
{
    // open the file
    ifstream file;
    file.open("4253512.txt");

    // program reads file and counts how many numbers in array.
    cout << "Reading from the file..." << endl;
    float i;
    int nElements = 0;
    while (file >> i) // checks whether it's good or not
    {
        nElements++;
    }
    cout << "The amount of numbers in the file are: " << nElements << endl;

    //put numbers into dynamic array

    int *arr = new int[nElements];
    for (i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
    {
        file >> arr[nElements];
    }

    // bubble sort the numbers

    bubbleSort(arr, nElements);

    // printing out the highest and lowest values

    printArray(arr, nElements);

    delete[] arr;
    file.close();

    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for(int i = j + 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(arr[j] > arr[i]) // swap if bigger
               swap(arr[j], arr[i]);
        }
    }
}


void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    cout << "The lowest value of the array is " << arr[0] <<
            " and the highest value is " << arr[n] << endl;
}
```

There are no runtime errors when I build and run btw.

Comment: Discuss `for (i = 0; i < nElements; i++) { file >> arr[nElements]; }` with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Focus the discussion on which array element is being read into.

Comment: Using vectors is banned, so how about using [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)?

Comment: @MikeCAT `std::deque` might be more performant here.

Comment: Also discuss how many elements are left in the file to be read after completing `while (file >> i) { nElements++; }`. Duckie may recommend seeking back to the beginning of the file before trying to read it again.

Comment: I think user4581301 is on the right track, alternative to the rubber duck, is cat, parent, co-worker, or any other who might listen :)

Comment: Got a bit of a mis-match here: `float i;` used in the first loop is reading floating point numbers. The second loop is reading integers. Could cause problems. Actually does cause problems. The `i` in `for (i = 0; i < nElements; i++)` is a float and that will screw up in interesting ways with very large lists when the precision is so bad that you can't see the effect of the `i++` any more. `i` should probably be an integer all the way through.

Comment: `arr[n]` in `printArray` is out-of-range.

Comment: _@Sean_ Please provide a [MCVE] please (emphasis on _minimal_). Remove all the irrelevant code while it still shows the behavior in question. User inputs can be replaced with hard coded data for such case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my apologies, i was sorta having trouble on the entire code but next time i'll try to keep it short and concise. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues with the code.
Not going to beginning of the file stream, passing values to array with nElements instead of i, accessing arr[n] instead of n-1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int[], int);
void printArray(int[], int);

int main()
{
    // open the file
    ifstream file;
    file.open("4253512.txt");

    // program reads file and counts how many numbers in array.
    cout << "Reading from the file..." << endl;
    float i;
    int nElements = 0;
    while (file >> i) // checks whether it's good or not
    {
        nElements++;
    }
    cout << "The amount of numbers in the file are: " << nElements << endl;

    //seek to beginning of file stream
    file.clear();
    file.seekg(0);
    //put numbers into dynamic array
    int* arr = new int[nElements];
    for (i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
    {
        //pass to i not nElements
        file >> arr[(int)i];
    }

    // bubble sort the numbers
    bubbleSort(arr, nElements);

    // printing out the highest and lowest values

    printArray(arr, nElements);

    delete[] arr;
    file.close();

    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int i = j + 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[i]) // swap if bigger
                swap(arr[j], arr[i]);
        }
    }
}


void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    cout << "The lowest value of the array is " << arr[0] <<
        //                                  n-1 not n
        " and the highest value is " << arr[n-1] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Rather than casting `i` to an `int` you might as well define it as an `int`.

Comment: Yes, just didn't want to change the code too much. I guess that's not a big of a chance.

Comment: Agree with the sentiment. The asker's not likely to see the bug unless they get a file with 8 million or so entries in it.

Comment: thank you pesuww!!! Yeah there were a couple errors my bad :/ i think the n-1 thing was a brainfart but nonetheless i appreciate the help! <3

Comment: Any time! Glad that fixed the issue and helped to clarify the usage of istream.

Comment: yea user4581301 i went and just put it inside the for loop but i understood what pesuww was doing